# Why is the set $W$ of all $n$ degrees polynomials not a subspace of $F(-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, vector-spaces

I am struggling to completely buy the argument for polynomial subspaces of degree $n$

Briefly, here is the argument for why the set $W$ of all $n$ degree polynomials is not a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$:

Let $W \in F(-\infty,\infty)$ be the set of all $n$ degree polynomials.  $W$ is not closed under addition, thus it is not a subspace:
Let 
$$
f(x) = c_n x^n+\cdots+c_3 x^2+c_2 x+c_1
$$
$$
g(x) = -c_nx^n+\cdots+c_3 x^2+c_2 x+c_1
$$
$$
h(x) = f(x)+g(x)
$$
Then
$$
h(x) = 2(c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_3 x^2+c_2 x+c_1)
$$
and $ h(x) \not\in W$.

**Okay, this argument is great - however, we could rewrite $h(x)$ as** 
$$
h(x) = 2(0x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_3 x^2+c_2 x+c_1)
$$
which would, by abuse of notation, allow $ h(x) \in W$

Phrased differently, why is

$$
0x^n\cdots ax^2+ bx + c
$$

not considered a polynomial of degree $n$?

Furthermore, we allow the null space to be a subspace of all spaces, and we define $0$ in all spaces.  We could write $f(x) = 0(x^n)$ and this would be the zero vector of this space.

Comment: The set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ is a subspace (provided you include the zero polynomial among what you consider to be those of degree $\le n$). But _exactly_ $n$ rather than less than or equal to $n$ is another matter.

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware of that argument.  I suppose that if one were to allow polynomials with $0x^n$  to be degree $n$, then any low degree polynomial could also be any high degree polynomial, and then degree is less useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your use of $h(x)$, and indeed $h(x) \notin W$. The reason: saying a polynomial "has degree $n$" implies the coefficient of $x^n$ is nonzero. So you writing $h(x)$ the way you did---including the term $0x^n$---means the coefficient of $x^n$ in $h(x)$ is not nonzero, so the degree of $h(x)$ cannot be $n$.